# save output from a program trough batch I did not find anything like this plss

Tags: batch-file

**So all I want to know is how do I make in a batch file something like:**

start a program (start ChromePass.exe) and then save what is in that program (All passwords and usernames) in a txt file but make it work on windows 10.

**On youtube it was something like:**

start ChromePass.exe / stext ChromePass.txt

**Found out the solution: The command lines were disabled by the creator. I just downloaded the Version 1.25.**

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to your two typing errors.

`ChormePass.exe` should be `ChromePass.exe` and `/ stext` should be `/stext`.

Like this:

```
Start ChromePass.exe /stext ChromePass.txt
```

*No need for YouTube, use the authors own [web page](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html)*